# How to configure OwnCloud and Reverse Proxy?

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, owncloud

Currently we do have multiple application servers that are physically separated to each other. We do also have multiple public IP address and planning to consolidate the web application server into one (1) public IP address.

As today, I am planning for our ownCloud to act as reverse proxy server and to be attached on one (1) public IP address. Our target was for ownCloud (Reverse Proxy Server) to redirect some page to different application / web servers.

E.g.

http://10.0.0.1/cloud - will redirect to OwnCloud/localhost

http://10.0.0.1/dtr - will redirect to Daily Time Record system (different system)

I am currently searching for Apache to do this and using mod_proxy. May I ask for more enlightenments? I am receiving-

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request GET /dtr.
>
> Reason: Error reading for remote server

Can owncloud and apache can act as reverse proxy server?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can I close this thread? I've created Apache reverse proxy server and it is working now properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use Apache reverse proxy module. For me, using ProxyPassReverse directly was not able to route back to the original route.

By using ProxyPass, ProxyHTMLURLMap and creation of link locations it did work out well.